# Checked checkbox slide up?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible?

```
var isChecked = $(".imdbArtistId").is(":checked").hide();
```

this does not work?

Can i do that by getting class of checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

The `is` method returns a value of true/false, not a jQuery object.

If you just want to hide checkboxes with the class you've specified if they're checked, you can do:

```
$(".imdbArtistId:checked").hide()
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KCLtD/)

Comment: is it possible to hide also the checkbox text.Beside text?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(".imdbArtistId").is(":checked"))
{
$(this).hide()
}
})
```

This will hide that checkbox if its checked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `hide` function on the element, not on the boolean result of `.is`

try this:

```
var element = $(this);
var isChecked = element.is(":checked");
if(isChecked){
   element.hide();
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/7XHrn/)

---

if you need to also hide some associated text you will need to be able to identify that matching text, this would be best done with a parent container to wrap both the checkbox and the element inside, something like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox"/> here is some text
</div>
```

and the you could use the following code:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    var isChecked = element.is(":checked");
    if (isChecked) {
        element.parent().hide();
    }
});​
```

[Here is that one in action](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/7XHrn/1/)

Comment: is it possible to hide also the checkbox text.Beside text?

Comment: @MertMetin: Of course it is, if you have them both wrapped in a containing element you can hide that instead [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/7XHrn/1/) ... if that don't help you then can you post some more of your html in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try having following structure:

```
<div class='placeholder'><input type='checkbox' /></div>
```

And then:

```
$(".imdbArtistId:checked").parent().hide();
```

Comment: OK, should work without parent as well. Was just expecting that the hide didn't work properly, but you had an error by using .is(), which returns a boolean :)

Comment: $(".ImdbAddArtist:checked").parent().hide(); this removes rest of all which is not added :S

Answer (score 0):

is(":checked") will return true or false, not return all the checked boxes.

For that, use :

```
$(".imdbArtistId:checked").hide();
```

assuming "imbdbArtistId" is a common class for all the checkboxes you are considering.